# How to post all rows where table row ID's are not in sequence

Tags: php, post, foreach

I have an HTML Table in a form. each table row has a unique ID. I have jquery adding and deleting rows. you can see the fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/gUYpL/

So every time a user adds a row, the counter is added to the row so for three rows you obviously have `first_name1,first_name2,first_name3`

if I then delete row 2, I then have `first_name1,first_name3`.

What is the best way to loop through each 'row' of post information?

so currently I use:

```
$i=1;
    while($i<=$maxid) {write info to database}
```

So 3 from first_name3... but actually only 2 rows as first_name2 deleted

Is there an option with foreach? Something like:

```
foreach ($lineid as $value) {
    write info to database
}
```

Apologies if this is an obvious question, just need some help.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: How about assigning the name attribute of each input when the user hit the submit button? That way you don't really have to care about the deletion problem.

Comment: naming each field will solve your issue and you can also use multi-index name convention if dynamic input box are created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I get this question completely but in PHP you can do:

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ($arr as $value) {
     $value = $value * 2;
}
// $arr is now array(2, 4, 6, 8)
```

Also you can work with array_keys and loop over that ;)

```
$array = array("name1" => "Ted", "name3" => "Dude");
$keys = array_keys($array);
for($i = 0; $i<sizeof($keys); $i++){
             echo $array[$keys[$i]]; //echo Ted and then Dude
}
```

This is not tested but I think this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

you should take your element position from last digit of your line id  'first_name3' 
so you can map it correctly and also assign it to a new array if you want only the actual count